# compiling libqxt in mac osx

Tags: macos, qt, makefile, libqxt

I have the latest (git) version of libqxt. I run `./configure` and that works just fine, then make fails with this error:

```
linking ../../lib/QxtWidgets.framework/QxtWidgets
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/pgsql/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/tmp/qt-stuff-85167/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.1/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/lib'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_CGSGetWindowProperty", referenced from:
      QxtWindowSystem::windowTitle(long)   in qxtwindowsystem_mac.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [../../lib/QxtWidgets.framework/QxtWidgets] Error 1
make: *** [sub-src-widgets-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

If it matters, I'm using OSX Mountain Lion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Seems like Qxt is using some private Mac OS X API that was removed in Mountain Lion. CGSGetWindowProperty was not documented in previous versions of Mac OS X, so I gues it wasn't reliable to use it anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking too... Do you think there's a way to get around this, or even find the header/lib somewhere else? If so, where?

Answer (score 4):

As a hacky fix you can just remove CGSGetWindowProperty property call - Qxt will compile , but of course `QxtWindowSystem::windowTitle` will not work correctly.

```
diff --git a/src/widgets/mac/qxtwindowsystem_mac.cpp b/src/widgets/mac/qxtwindowsystem_mac.cpp
index 63cab38..de4a89c 100644
--- a/src/widgets/mac/qxtwindowsystem_mac.cpp
+++ b/src/widgets/mac/qxtwindowsystem_mac.cpp
@@ -89,11 +89,7 @@ QString QxtWindowSystem::windowTitle(WId window)
     // most of CoreGraphics private definitions ask for CGSValue as key but since
     // converting strings to/from CGSValue was dropped in 10.5, I use CFString, which
     // apparently also works.
-    err = CGSGetWindowProperty(connection, window, (CGSValue)CFSTR("kCGSWindowTitle"), &windowTitle);
-    if (err != noErr) return QString();
-
-    // this is UTF8 encoded
-    return QCFString::toQString((CFStringRef)windowTitle);
+    return QString();
 }

 QRect QxtWindowSystem::windowGeometry(WId window)
```

For the future reference you can monitor [this issue in libqxt repository](http://dev.libqxt.org/libqxt/issue/27/building-fails-under-mac-os-x-108).

Comment: Hi, if possible, can you answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28708747/error-trying-to-install-qxt-for-sending-email ? I did the fix you said, I got the error during the `make install` step..