# Error trying to install Qxt for sending email

Tags: c++, macos, qt, makefile, libqxt

I need to use the `QxtSMTP` module to be able to send email through Qt. I downloaded the package from [here](https://github.com/mnutt/libqxt). As per the instructions, I did `.configure` and `make`. During `make install`, it threw an error - (OS X, 10.10)

```
/Users/Cupidvogel/Desktop/mail/libqxt-master/src/core/qxtglobal.cpp:201: Undocumented parameter 'PUB' in QXT_P()
/Users/Cupidvogel/Desktop/mail/libqxt-master/src/core/qxtglobal.cpp:201: No such parameter 'QXT_DECLARE_PUBLIC' in QXT_P()
qdoc3(31442,0x7fff79948300) malloc: *** error for object 0x1109c1a40: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
/bin/sh: line 1: 31442 Abort trap: 6 ( QXT_SOURCE_TREE=/Users/Cupidvogel/Desktop/mail/libqxt-master QXT_BUILD_TREE=/Users/Cupidvogel/Desktop/mail/libqxt-master /Users/Cupidvogel/Desktop/mail/libqxt-master/tools/3rdparty/qdoc3/qdoc3 -DQXT_DOXYGEN_RUN /Users/Cupidvogel/Desktop/mail/libqxt-master/doc/src/qxt.qdocconf )
make: *** [adp_docs] Error 134
```

As a result of which I am unable to get the libraries installed. How do I fix this?

And secondly, I need the header files and libraries required to send email. I don't want to do it the *README* file suggests - by configuring **Qxt** and **CONFIG** variables. So which libraries do I need to link?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to send email and don't want to configure **Qxt** and **CONFIG** variables, why not do the following.

Copy the `src/network/qxtsmtp.h` and `src/network/qxtsmtp.cpp` files to your project folder and add them as existing files to your project (right click on your project). Now also do this for all files that these 2 files depend on for the qxt library. In example, `src/network/qxtsmtp.h` depends on `#include "qxtglobal.h"`and `#include "qxtmailmessage.h"`.

Once you've done this program the connect to the smtp server and send a short message. Try to compile this and fix the issues.

Another option could be to use [MailCore](http://libmailcore.com/#gettingcode). It also has instructions to build on MacOS: https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2/blob/master/build-mac/README.md